# Table for $\mathbb{Z_4}/2\mathbb{Z_4}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

I need to create a table for Table for $\mathbb{Z_4}/2\mathbb{Z_4}$ to show that it's an integral domain by showing that the product of two nonzero elements is never zero.

$$\mathbb{Z}_4 = \{0,1,2,3\}$$
$$2\mathbb{Z}_4 = \{0,2\}$$

The congruence classes are:

$$[0] = 0 + 2\mathbb{Z}_4 = 2\mathbb{Z}_4$$
$$[1] = 1+2\mathbb{Z_4} = \{1,3\}$$
$$[2] = 2 + 2\mathbb{Z}_4 = \{2,0\}$$
$$[3] = 3 + 2\mathbb{Z}_4 = \{3, 1\} = [1]$$

So there are $3$ congruence classes, right? I need to create a table for them, but how I'm supposed to multiply these things? I'm lost

Comment: Shouldn't your equivalence classes read $\dots n + 2 \mathbb{Z}_4 \dots $ ?

Comment: @erfink ops, yes, edited

Comment: $\{2,0\}=[0]$ surely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing $\mathbb{Z}_4/2\mathbb{Z}_4$ means that $x\sim y \iff x-y\in 2\mathbb{Z}_4$, which in this case means $$\mathbb{Z}_4/2\mathbb{Z}_4=\{\bar0,\bar1\}\cong \mathbb{Z}_2$$ which is in fact an integral domain (every field is in fact an integral domain but you can also write down a table to check it out).

Comment: what's wrong with my multiplications?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs you just wrote the classes (and actually there are 2 rather than 3). The multiplication of classes is given by $\bar a\cdot\bar b=(a+R)\cdot(b+R)=ab+R$.

Answer (score 0):

In order to multiply two classes pick a representative of each class, make their product and look up in whi!ch class this product lies, this class is the product of the two cleaases (and is independent of the choice of representatives if and only if the quotient is made by an ideal, that is the reasion of the definition of an ideal).